# TikZ poster class: Is possible to access variables that define lengths and dimensions for block, inner block, etc?

Tags: tikzposter

I mean, if I use e.g. `\blockwidth` for setting a width of `tikzfigure` environment, I get a undefined control sequence error. In that case one workaround is using `\linewidth`, but I need to subtract the separation distance from the edge of the box, and I could not access that separation as well.

Obviously, when one defines custom styles for elements, dimensions are well defined, as one can read in the documentation.

But, is there any way to access them inside the body of the poster?

I think it is difficult and not relevant in this case to give a MWE. Nevertheless, I give it.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\title{Title} \institute{Inst}
\author{Auth} \titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}
\begin{document}
 \maketitle
 \block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
 \begin{columns}
  \column{0.3}
  \block{BlocktitleB}{
   \newlength{\figw}
   \setlength{\figw}{\blockwidth}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \pgfplotsset{
    height=0.5*\figw,
    width=0.5*\figw,
   }
   \begin{axis}[
                xmin=1.5,
                xmax=5
               ]
    \addplot[
             solid,
             line width=0.8mm,
             samples=100,
             domain=1.5:5,
             restrict y to domain=0.6:2.2
            ] {0.7+(2.22/x)};
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \column{0.7}
  \block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
  \note{Notetext}
 \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

This gives an undefined control sequence error and a zero length warning.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Always appreciated if you can add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to a question. For some questions it is entirely necessary to be able to answer, and in most other cases it is nice to not have to make up a complete example for testing.

Comment: A MWE is always helpful!

Comment: With regard to a `pgfplots` `axis`, the problem is that when you set the width to X, `pgfplots` sets the width of the axis box alone to X-45pt, and then it adds ticklabels/axis labels afterwards. The 45pt is fixed, `pgfplots` doesn't measure the width of ticklabels etc. In your case, the labels are wider than 45pt because of the font size, so the total width of the diagram becomes wider than the specified size. This is a general problem of `pgfplots`. But going back to your question, I think you can access those lengths, will likely add an answer in a bit.

Comment: Thanks @TorbjørnT, for that remark. I am also checking the tikzposter.cls. I never used before xkeyval package, but all the definitions of lengths are managed with it. Then I think every time some element of the poster is called, the keys are set with the information given by the style and user input. Then the problem reduces to how to access the keys of each element instance.

Comment: Look at the definition of the `\block` macro, note that for example that if you're in a `\column`, then the `\TP@blockbodywidth` is set to `\colwidth`. And later, the text in the block is put in a `\parbox` of width `\TP@blockbodywidth-2\TP@blockbodyinnersep-\TP@blockbodyoffsetx`. (By the way, the class defines a `tikzfigure` environment, but the width of that cannot be set -- it will be `\linewidth` -- and you're not using it in your example.) I wont have time to write an answer right now, maybe later if I figure things out. But don't hesitate to add an answer yourself.

Comment: @TorbjørnT do not worry, thanks for the guidance. I will try to figure it out and give an answer. If that is not possible, I will be glad to see yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in a `columns` environment, the total width of a `\block` is `\colwidth`. The width of the text block is `\linewidth`. Those two are always available I believe.

The code below demonstrates how to define additional macros to access the dimensions that the class defines. This is not a definitive list of course, but I suppose it should cover most cases.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a1paper]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{pgfplots,array}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\title{Title} \institute{Inst}
\author{Auth} \titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}

% define macros without @
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\blockwidth}{\TP@blockbodywidth}
\newcommand{\blockinnersep}{\TP@blockbodyinnersep}
\newcommand{\innerblockwidth}{\TP@innerblockbodywidth}
\newcommand{\innerblockinnersep}{\TP@innerblockbodyinnersep}
\makeatother

\newcommand\printtable{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\ttfamily\textbackslash}ll}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Existing macros:} \\
colwidth            & \the\colwidth \\
linewidth           & \the\linewidth \\[10pt]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{New macros:} \\
blockwidth          & \the\blockwidth \\
blockinnersep       & \the\blockinnersep \\
innerblockwidth & \the\innerblockwidth \\
innerblockinnersep  & \the\innerblockinnersep
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

% demonstrates extent of text block
X\dotfill X}


\newcommand\printdimensions{%
% the background and frame of a block is drawn by a node named blockbody
% use that to draw some lines
\draw
let
\p1=(blockbody.south west),\p2=(blockbody.south east),\n1={scalar(\x2-\x1)}
in
[red,Bar-Bar,ultra thick] (\x1,\y1-4cm) coordinate (a) -- (\x2,\y2-4cm) coordinate (b)
node[midway,above] {$\mathtt{blockwidth} \approx \n1\,\mathrm{pt}$};

\draw [dashed,red] (blockbody.west) -- ([yshift=-1cm]a);
\draw [dashed,red] (blockbody.east) -- ([yshift=-1cm]b);

\draw
let
\p1=(blockbody.south west),\p2=(blockbody.south east),\n1={scalar(\x2-\x1-2*\blockinnersep)}
in
[blue,Bar-Bar,ultra thick] (\x1+\blockinnersep,\y2-2cm) coordinate (a) -- (\x2-\blockinnersep,\y2-2cm) coordinate (b)
node[midway,above] {$\mathtt{linewidth} \approx \n1\,\mathrm{pt}$};

\draw [dashed,blue] ([yshift=6cm]a) -- ([yshift=-1cm]a);
\draw [dashed,blue] ([yshift=6cm]b) -- ([yshift=-1cm]b);
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{columns}
\column{0.4}

  \block{BlocktitleB}{\printtable}
  \printdimensions

\column{0.6}

  \block[bodyinnersep=50pt]{BlocktitleC}{\printtable}
  \printdimensions

\note{Notetext}
\end{columns}


\block[bodyoffsety=-4cm,titleoffsety=-5cm]{BlocktitleA}{
\printtable
\innerblock{Inner}{\printtable}
}
\printdimensions

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `\linewidth` inside the block the separation towards the boarders are already subtracted, see the width of the rule in the following example:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Basic}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
 \block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
 \begin{columns}
  \column{0.3}
  \block{BlocktitleB}{
   \newlength{\figw}
   \setlength{\figw}{\linewidth}
     \rule{\figw}{2pt}

     \lipsum
  }
 \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The better question is why your pgf plot is wider than the linewidth. `tikz` automatically places some padding around your plot, which you can disable with `inner sep=0pt`.

However I would make the plot a bit larger then `\linewidth` (about 1 %) to align the right axis with the boarder of the surrounding text, even if the `5` on the x axis now slightly protrudes into the margin.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetheme{Basic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{printlen}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
 \block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
 \begin{columns}
  \column{0.3}
  \block{BlocktitleB}{

    \lipsum[2]

   \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]%
       \begin{axis}[%
                    width=1.01\linewidth,
                    xmin=1.5,%
                    xmax=5%,
                   ]%
        \addplot[%
                 solid,%
                 line width=0.8mm,%
                 samples=100,%
                 domain=1.5:5,%
                 restrict y to domain=0.6:2.2%
                ] {0.7+(2.22/x)};%
       \end{axis}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
 \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that is not the case when you use it with a tikzfigure, the box of the plot, using \linewidth, is directly over block edge. Notwithstanding, that is not the answer to the question, since the question, as clearly stated, was if there is some way to access, from within the document, the lengths defined by the class, such \blockwidth and the separator.

Comment: @elessartelkontar That's a problem of the pgf plot and not with the width. `\linewidth` is the length you asked for in the question.

Comment: and how I get the inner block width. And \blockwidth or \linewidth was only an example